# Complex update query in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to execute SQL query like this

```
update objs a set a.dirSize= sum(files.fileSize)
inner join objs files on files.fullPath like a.fullPath||'\%' and files.isDir=0
where a.isDir=1
group by a.fullPath
```

In DB Browser for SQLite 3.9.1, but this query fails with error

```
near "a": syntax error:
```

How to fix and execute such SQL query?

Thank you!

Comment: sqlite doesn't support joins in update. you have to use correlated sub-queries to get what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite doesn't support joins in `update`. You have to use correlated sub-queries to get what you need.

```
update objs 
set dirSize= (select sum(fileSize)
              from files 
              where fullPath like objs.fullPath||'\%' and isDir=0)
where isDir=1
```

Edit: Per OP, the table involved is the same.

```
update objs 
set dirSize= (select sum(b.fileSize) 
              from objs b 
              where b.fullPath like objs.fullPath||'\%' and b.isDir=0)
where isDir=1
```

Comment: ok, but what if files and dirs are in the same table 'objs'? `update objs a
set a.dirSize= (select sum(b.fileSize)
              from objs b
              where b.fullPath like a.fullPath||'\%' and b.isDir=0)
where a.isDir=1` doesn't work too.

Comment: i don't think you can use aliases as well.

Comment: try `update objs  set dirSize= (select sum(b.fileSize) from objs b where b.fullPath like objs.fullPath||'\%' and b.isDir=0) where isDir=1`

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much!